# How to stack different divs on each other (should be responsive)

Tags: html, css

I have just started to deal with HTML and CSS. I would like to stack different divs  (see picture).

The black div represents the container. The red div a header and the blue one a circle which is centered and has the center at the bottom edge of the red div.

The solution should finally also be responsive. What do I have to consider here?

[image]

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.circle {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Responsive" isn't a term that explains anything. It merely means "changes under certain conditions". You need to be more specific about _how_ and _when_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `position` and `flexbox`

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `header` relative, and align circle to bottom with `translate`.

```css
.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  height: 40%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative; /* make header container relative */
}

.circle {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  
  /* bottom position with centered circle */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, 50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<!-- Option with bigger header -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="header" style="height: 70%;">
    <div class="circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. in `transform: translate3d(-50%, 50%, 0);` what is the effect of thirth number?

Comment: It's `tz` vector, sometimes helpful with layer render issues